# How to *use* Hamster with the GNOME shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, hamster

I installed `hamster-applet` and `gnome-shell-extensions-hamster`. But I can't see how to actually use it efficiently. It looks like this:

[image]

How can I start tracking time for a specific project from this "applet"?

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

Found an integration with the app-indicator in the bottom of the screen with instructions at
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/install-hamster-indicator-time-tracking.html

---

The Gnome shell integration is still lacking in Hamtster

there is 1 other project working on this at github that seems to be a bit further along than the official package

https://github.com/tbaugis/hamster-shell-extension

For official updates you can always follow the official blog at
http://projecthamster.wordpress.com

So unfortunately there isn't a clean integration yet -- I've found that running the program as a stand alone works rather well - the default location is

```
/usr/bin/hamster-time-tracker
```

Press Alt+F2 and paste that line in - should pop right up as a stand alone window

Comment: Thanks, but what's different about the extension on github? I installed it and it looks exactly the same ... and "Show overview" doesn't even work. - Using it stand alone is not an option for me. I'm terribly undisciplined in that way.

Comment: Interface wise there are few differences, though the code in the backend is better maintained. An option I've thought about though haven't implemented is setting a HotKey to add a task to Hamster. 

Wish I could offer better news, though there is a Unity plugin that I haven't worked with.... I've been using https://www.toggl.com since switching to Gnome-Shell -- makes a decent web-app through Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what it looks like on Gnome 3.  What version are you using, with what Ubuntu version?

On Ubuntu Maverick, I've installed the latest version from git.

When I left-click on the applet in the panel, the applet looks like this:

[image]

It is a simple matter of entering the project name or whatever other name I want to provide, adding a possible tag, and hitting "enter".  It then starts adding to my time for that project.  I can see reports, etc, by doing a right-click on the applet in the panel, run reporting tools, export data in html, iCal, xml, python, etc.

In your case it looks like you just need to type in the project name and hit enter.  Thay may be enough for you to track your time, and then use the stand-alone GUI for reporting etc.  Again I'm not sure what else is different in the Gnome 3 GUI, or what exactly you're looking for, but the [Project Hamster](http://projecthamster.wordpress.com/) site has lots more info, and several ways to provide input or bug reports.